# How to solve a derivative?

Tags: derivatives

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=k$$
$$x=me^{s/n}$$
How to derive $s(t)$, the changes of $s$ by $t$?

$m$ and $n$ are constants. $k$ is also constant for the given condition.

Comment: $x$ appears not to depend on $t$, unless $s$ depends on $t$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I edited the question to make sense.

Comment: By differentiation of the second line you can find a differential equation for $s$, but you lack conditions to find an expression for $s(t)$.

Comment: make more sense! if k is a constant then add this to the problem description. if x is a function of tt han add this to the problem description.

Comment: @miracle173 sorry for the incomplete description. Yes, $k$ is constant for the condition we are solving. $x$ is a function of $t$, but we do not have the function. We just know that $dx/dt=k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = k$, then $x(t)$ is a linear polynomial.

$x(t) = me^{s(t)/n} = kt + C$

$\ln{e^{s(t)/n}} = \ln{\dfrac{kt+C}{m}}$

$s(t) = n\ln{\dfrac{kt+C}{m}}$

Comment: How to get $C$?

Comment: $C$ can be arbitrary, e.g. any function of this form $s(t) = n\ln{\dfrac{kt+C}{m}}$ will satisfy the equations in your problem. Sometimes, in problems like this one, $s(0)$ is given, which allows to figure out the exact value of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {dx}{dt}=k\\
x=kt+C\\
kt+C = me^{s(t)/n}\\
s(t) = n \ln (\frac {k}{m} t+C)$